# What is the use of <permission-group> in android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

From android documentation, Its clear that
Using "permission-group" we can create a permission group.
Using "permission" element in android manifest file, we can define a permission.
This permission can be added to permission-group.

if we name this permission-group as "com.example.permission-group"
can we use it in another application using "uses-permission".
If we can use, whether can we access all the permissions of this group.

If the above case is wrong, Then how can we make use of "permission-group"

Comment: Permission-group holds list of permissions that's fine... But there may be some use of this group. what exactly it is. Only for storing permissions?

Answer (score 16):

The tag  permission-group is just used to group one or more permissions under a particular category. From the developer's site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-group-element.html

```
Declares a name for a logical grouping of related permissions. Individual 
permission join the group through the permissionGroup attribute of the
<permission> element. Members of a group are presented together in the 
user interface.

Note that this element does not declare a permission itself, only a category in 
which permissions can be placed. See the <permission> element for element for
information on declaring permissions and assigning them to groups.
```

For example, the messages related permissions, say android.permission.SEND_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS and all the permissions related to messages are grouped under android.permission-group.MESSAGES to have a common icon.

From AndroidManifest.xml of android source https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <permission-group android:name="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
    android:label="@string/permgrouplab_messages"
    android:icon="@drawable/perm_group_messages"
    android:description="@string/permgroupdesc_messages"
    android:permissionGroupFlags="personalInfo"
    android:priority="360"/>

  <!-- Allows an application to monitor incoming SMS messages, to record
     or perform processing on them. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:label="@string/permlab_receiveSms"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_receiveSms" />

<!-- Allows an application to send SMS messages. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:permissionFlags="costsMoney"
    android:label="@string/permlab_sendSms"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_sendSms" />
```

Here, the android.permission-group.MESSAGES categorises these permissions under a common icon and name in permissions when your applications uses these permissions.

Give

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

in a sample application to see the result. Those two permissions will be grouped into a common category.

[image: Note the Receive and send sms categorised into a group]

The costs money is because of the android:permissionFlags="costsMoney" in SEND_SMS permission. Hence permission-group is only used to categorise the permissions. It cannot be used as in  to group one or more permissions.

Answer (score 5):

The `permission-group` tag allows you to create a `group` of custom permissions.

> Declares a name for a logical grouping of related permissions. Individual permission join the group through the permissionGroup attribute of the permission element.

It basically allows you to organize your permissions in an orderly fashion.

> And permission-group defines a label for a set of permissions (both
>   those declared in the manifest with permission elements and those
>   declared elsewhere). It affects only how the permissions are grouped
>   when presented to the user. The permission-group element does not
>   specify which permissions belong to the group; it just gives the group
>   a name.

```
<manifest . . . >

<permission-group android:description="string resource"
              android:icon="drawable resource"
              android:label="string resource"
              android:name="SomeGroup" />

<permission android:description="string resource"
        android:icon="drawable resource"
        android:label="string resource"
        android:name="SomePermission"
        android:permissionGroup="SomeGroup"
        android:protectionLevel=["normal" | "dangerous" | 
                                 "signature" | "signatureOrSystem"] />

    <uses-permission android:name="SomePermission" />
    . . .
    <application . . .>
        <activity android:name="com.some.activity"
                  android:permission="SomePermission"
                  . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, Thats what i got it from android doc. But here we created the permission-group with some name, and it holds some permissions. My question is whether can we access This permission-group in any other application, so that application can access all the permissions of this permission group

Comment: You could try creating an Android Library that contains nothing but a manifest file containing the necessary `<permission-group>` and `<permission>` definitions. You might be able to access those definitions from your application through the library. How to create a library: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

dangerous authorizations are organized into groups related to the capabilities or functionality of a device.

Authorizations are divided into nine groups, allowing for group-level authorization requests to be processed.

A single group of authorizations corresponds to multiple authorizations declarations on the manifest.
[image: permission group arbre]

[image: group permission]